# How is 'isSubclassOfClass' not a valid selector when it is defined in NSObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, inheritance, selector

I am trying to do some debugging on a project I am working on, and would like to know the kind of ViewController a specific variable is being assigned.  So I created an if statement like so:

```
    if ([controller isSubclassOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        NSLog(@"It's a navigation controller!");

    }
```

'controller' is created just above using

```
DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController]topViewController];
```

DetailViewController is a simple class inheriting from UIViewController.  However I'm getting a compiler error saying `No visibile @interface for 'DetailViewController' declares the selector 'isSubclassOfClass:'`

How is that possible?  When I tripleTap the reference for isSubclassOfClass it says it's a class method defined in NSObject.  How is it possible that DetailViewController doesn't know that selector since all objects inherit from NSObject??

Comment: as others have said the mistake is controller is not a class object so you can't call isSubclassOfClass on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both other responders gave you a correct answer to your question, but I wanted to clarify something.

Methods who's declaration start with a + are CLASS methods. The class object implements those methods, not instances of that class. So this method:

```
+ (BOOL)isSubclassOfClass:(Class)aClass
```

Is a class method.

You'd use it like Jeffery Thomas demonstrated in the first part of his answer:

```
[[controller class] isSubclassOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]
```

The `[controller class]` bit fetches the class object for the controller object, and then sends that class object the isSubclassOfClass message.

In contrast, the method `isKindOfClass:`

```
- (BOOL)isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass
```

...is an instance method. You can tell because it's declaration starts with a "-" instead of a "+". Learn to look for the "+" or "-" at the beginning of every method declaration to see if it's a class method or an instance method. And if the compiler isn't letting you send a message that you see in the docs, go back and double-check. I've been programming in Objective-C for quite a few years now and this still bites me occasionally.

You send the `isKindOfClass` message to an instance of the object you want to test for class membership:

```
[controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]
```

Answer (score 4):

The standard way of doing this is `-isKindOfClass:`, not `+isSubclassOfClass:`, but it's possible to use `+isSubclassOfClass:`.

Using the instance method `-isKindOfClass:`

```
if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    NSLog(@"It's a navigation controller!");
}
```

Using the class method `+isSubclassOfClass:`

```
if ([[controller class] isSubclassOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    NSLog(@"It's a navigation controller!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> When I tripleTap the reference for isSubclassOfClass it says it's a **class method** defined in NSObject.

It's a class method, and you're using it on an instance. Try `isKindOfClass`.